# How to add to an array

Tags: javascript

I have an empty array and can an add to it like so:

```
test.theme = [

];

test.theme.default = ['blue','pink','orange'];
```

How can I hard code default in to the theme array instead of first declaring the array and then adding to it?

I've been trying

```
test.theme = [
    default: ['blue','pink','orange']
]
```

Can't seem to get the right syntax.

Comment: First example you're attaching a property to the array object, not as an index of the array, so your `test.theme.length==0`. In second example is not valid syntax. Do you want an object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first object is not an array, it's an object. Do it like this:

```
test.theme = {
    default: ['blue','pink','orange']
}
```

Comment: @MikeRifgin Good - note that you won't be able to use `.push()` or `.slice()` or `.length` on your "test.theme" object, but that may be what you want.

Answer (score 3):

The array literal syntax makes no provisions for attaching properties (other than the implicitly-numbered properties, of course).  You have to add the "default" property in a different statement, and you'll have to do it like this:

```
test.theme["default"] = ['blue', 'pink', 'orange'];
```

if you don't want some IE versions to get upset. (The word "default" is a JavaScript keyword.)